# "git: 'lfs' is not a git command" on macOS

Tags: git, macos, git-lfs

```
LFS git: 'lfs' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

I am facing this issue on macOS. The `git lfs` command is working fine from the Terminal. But when I am running this command from some script it is trying to find the `lfs` command in git, and that is what I understand so far.

Please help me out in fixing this.

Comment: You've installed a custom version of Git on your system. You also have a non-custom version of Git—a standard install—on your system. When you run commands from a Terminal window, which Git do you use? When you run them from your IDE or whatever this other program may be, which Git do you use? (These are exercises for you to solve, which should, ideally, lead you to whatever the actual solution may be. Since I do not have your scripts, I cannot guess how to make them use the desired Git version.)

Comment: It is the standard version of Git that is shipped with macos

Comment: You said "it is", as if there is only *one* version of Git on your system, but this is not the case. There are *two* versions of Git on your system.

Comment: Can you modify the PATH from your scripts so that it points to the same git binary as the one you run from your terminal? Maybe check the PATH from your script and compare it with the PATH from your terminal. Then adjust the PATH from the script to match the one from the terminal.

Answer (score 47):

- Homebrew user run

```
brew install git-lfs
```

- MacPorts user run

```
port install git-lfs
```

Verify that the installation was successful:

```
$ git lfs install
> Git LFS initialized.
```

For more details refer to this doc: https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/installing-git-large-file-storage

Comment: please read the description again, I already mentioned that git lfs is installed and it is accessible by terminal but not by some programming script 
And FYI it is installed using hombrew

Comment: it is Eagle CAD script, you might not able to understand it

Comment: Worth mentioning that, in addition to Homebrew or MacPorts, you can install directly, as [welch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65800906/1028230) suggests.

Comment: This works! I installed with `brew install git-lfs`, and pushed successfully with LFS, but still couldn't run `git lfs checkout` before running `git lfs install`.

Answer (score 7):

When using the apple xcode-provided git, in `/usr/bin/git`, and after installing the git-lfs download from `https://git-lfs.github.com/`, you'll find git-lfs was placed in `/usr/local/bin/git-lfs`. You may need to add `/usr/local/bin` to your PATH so that git can find this. (I've not looked to see what brew and macports do)

Comment: for me, `/usr/local/bin` is already in my path.  This only happens when trying to use git-lfs from a third-party application (matlab).  I was wondering if putting a symlink to `/usr/local/bin/git-lfs` in `/usr/bin/git-lfs` would work, or if there's some way to force matlab to search in `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Appending `/usr/local/bin` to the PATH from within the application was the key for me. `[~, result] = system('echo -n $PATH'); result = [result ':/usr/local/bin']; setenv('PATH', result);` (in matlab)

Comment: make sure that mac has properly set the path, even after exporting and re-sourcing the rc file before giving up on this sltn

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using MacPorts or Homebrew, there is an installer for macOS here:

Git Large File Storage
https://git-lfs.com/

1. Download the correct file and extract
2. Then run `sudo ./install.sh`

That's pretty much it.

If you need a refresher on how to use:

```bash
# 1)  Setup Git LFS on your system. You only have to do this once per user account:

git lfs install

# 2) Configure the file types or paths to be tracked using

git lfs track "*.bin"

# 3) Then just add the files as usual with git add command

# Tracked files can also be configured manually using the .gitattributes file
```

Comment: navigating to the downloaded folder and running sudo ./install.sh worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another way for the mac users who doesn't have brew, you can install git lfs using conda

```
conda install git-lfs
```